# SQL SMS - Error - There is already an object named "genre" in the database

Tags: sql, database, object, exists

I'm trying to create a hypothetical videostore database and this error message comes up everytime I execute this query:

```
DROP DATABASE videostore
CREATE DATABASE videostore

CREATE TABLE genre
(
  genre_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  genre_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE classification
(    
  rating    VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT classification_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  description    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,    
  minimum_age    INT    NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE format

(    
  format_id    INT    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT format_pk PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  format_name    VARCHAR(8)    NOT NULL,        
  purchase_cost    FLOAT    NOT NULL
);        

CREATE TABLE rental_cost
(    
  rental_cost_id    INT    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT rental_cost_pk PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  rental_name    VARCHAR(15)    NOT NULL,
  rental_cost    FLOAT    NOT NULL,
  rental_days    TINYINT    NOT NULL    
);        

CREATE TABLE customer    
(    
  customer_id    INT    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  first_name    VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,        
  surname    VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,        
  dob    DATETIME    NOT NULL,        
  home_address    VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,        
  contact_number    VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,        
  referrer_id    INT    NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer(customer_id),    
);

CREATE TABLE movie    

(    
  movie_id    INT    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT movie_pk PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  movie_name    VARCHAR(40)    NOT NULL,        
  year    SMALLINT    NOT NULL,        
  duration    SMALLINT    NULL,         
  descrip    VARCHAR(120)    NULL,         
  classification    VARCHAR(2)    NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES classification(rating),
  rental_cost_id    INT    NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES rental_cost(rental_cost_id),    
);

CREATE TABLE copy
(    
  copy_id    INT    NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT copy_pk PRIMARY KEY    IDENTITY,
  movie_id    INT    NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES movie(movie_id),    
  format_id    INT    NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES format(format_id),    
);

CREATE TABLE rental
(    
  rental_id    INT    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT rental_pk PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  copy_id    INT    NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES copy(copy_id),    
  customer_id    INT    NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer(customer_id),    
  rental_date    DATETIME    NOT NULL,        
  return_date    DATETIME    NULL        
);

CREATE TABLE genre_movie                

(    
  genre_id    INT    NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES genre(genre_id),    
  movie_id    INT    NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES movie(movie_id),
  CONSTRAINT genre_movie_pk PRIMARY KEY (genre_id, movie_id)
);
```

(Sorry it's not in the correct format for reading a script with ease, I just really couldn't work out how to do that.)

Basically when I execute the SQL script it tells me that the object 'genre' already exists, but I can't see it anywhere else in my code.
And the table shouldn't already exist because I drop the database each time the script is executed right?

Sidenote - if there's a better way to make it so the database is dropped only if it exists please help me with that also.

Appreciate it.

Comment: You can use `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS videostore;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `USE videostore` after the `CREATE DATABASE videostore`. Otherwise you are creating tables in whatever database you are currently in.

Comment: Hold up, I need to be able to execute this script multiple times, and if I run it a second time is says: "Cannot drop database "videostore" because it is currently in use." How Do I work around that?

Comment: @Owen, Make sure that your current database is not `videostore` before you drop the database. Lets say that you have a database `master` you could add `use master;` as your first statement in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are executing this in the context of the `master` database.  If you check it you will probably see all your tables are actually in `master`.

Change the first part to this:

```
DROP DATABASE videostore
CREATE DATABASE videostore

USE videostore

CREATE TABLE genre
```

Comment: Ha simple enough. Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Hold up, I need to be able to execute this script multiple times, and if I run it a second time is says:
 "Cannot drop database "videostore" because it is currently in use."
How Do I work around that?

Comment: Do you have another window running against it?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally best to execute sql statements when required - try:

```
DROP DATABASE videostore
GO

CREATE DATABASE videostore
GO

USE videostore
CREATE TABLE genre
(
  genre_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  genre_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);
GO
```

etc.